# What's the difference between Mingw32 and Mingw64 include files?

Tags: winapi, mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

I used Mingw32 and devc++ IDE to develop my application. I included the lib files and include files of Mingw32 and compiled my application.

My application should run in both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of windows. My doubt here is whether my application run in windows 64 bit system? Even if it works perfectly will there be any problem?

What is the difference between Mingw32 and Mingw64 include files? My ultimate aim is to run my   application both in 32-bit and 64-bit windows. What include files should I add and compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mingw-w64 is fork of the mingw project.

Generally the mingw-w64 headers are much more complete, they include more recent additions from newer Windows (new SDK headers, function declarations, types, constants, macros), are ready for building 64-bit targets (when used with gcc capable of that).

Note of course that you cannot mix mingw's gcc with mingw-w64 headers or vice versa. You have to use complete toolchain from one or the other. I don't know how easy it is to switch toolchain in the devc++ (I don't use it).